# node mysql connection pool release

Tags: mysql, node.js

```
pool.getConnection(function(err, connection){
       connection.query("QUERY 1", function(err, rows){
           if(err){
             "DO I NEED to RELEASE connection?"
           }else{
                connection.query("QUERY 2", function(err, rows2){
                    if(err){
                        "DO I NEED to RELEASE connection?"
                    }else{
                        connection.release();
                    }
                });
           }
    });
});
```

Should I release the connection in all places?
What is the most efficient way to release the connection?

Comment: It's probably easier to use [`pool.query()`](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#pooling-connections).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [documentation](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql) states:

> When you are done with a connection, just call connection.release()
>   and the connection will return to the pool, ready to be used again by
>   someone else.

I assume that if getConnection does not return an error (a condition not checked in your code sample) then you have to release that connection in order for it to return to the pool, regardless if subsequent operations on it fail.

If you want to make sure, you can test it for example by setting the number of maximum connections in a pool to 1, generate an error condition and don't release the connection. You probably won't be able to get another connection.

Comment: There will be max timeout in milliseconds.. so i believe no need to release the connection, And most cases it supports many connections right? I have not faced any issues till now.

Answer (score 1):

use 'try' 'catch' syntax and in 'finally' block release once.